# schedule.schedulejob is not working as expected

Tags: node.js, heroku

We need to send inactive message to client after 3 days. But somehow the schedulejob is not sending message.

Code base:

```
var job = schedule.scheduleJob(senderId, Date.now() + 246060*1000, 
    function(fireDate){
        console.log("Schedulling - message1 triggered for:"+senderId+"with score: "+playerScore);
    });
```

Comment: what package are you using for scheduling?

Comment: I am using Node.js

Comment: "node-schedule": "^1.3.0"